# How do I get the claim details from Azure B2C Angular app if I use MSAL 2.0 & PKCE

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I followed instructions on the [page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-b2c-sample) to create an angular app to use with **MSAL 2.0** and **AD B2C**. I'm able to login and see the data in the **Local Storage**. Please see the picture below:

My questions are:

1. Should I see the following data for `credentialType` and `clientId` and `authorityType` in the **Local Storage**?
2. What should I do now to get the address and few other details of this logged in user?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s expected to see this on the client. You can configure it between local or session storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-between-browser-tabs

```
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "abcd-ef12-gh34-ikkl-ashdjhlhsdg"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage' //sessionstorage
    }
}
```

Use getAccount() to fetch the claim set from the token.

```
function signIn() {
  myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
    .then(loginResponse => {
        console.log("id_token acquired at: " + new Date().toString());

        if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
          updateUI();
        }
```

Comment: I think your code is not angular. In the angular project, the client is making a **http** call to server to get the profile. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-b2c-sample/src/app/profile/profile.component.ts).